# How to replace the last occurence of the character in .net

Tags: html, .net, string

i want to replace the last occurence of `<li>` to add class inside it, it should look like below. `<li class="last">`

```
<li><span>Vislink Acquires Gigawave for US$6 Million </span></li>
<li><span>Newegg Offers $25 7-inch DTV</span></li>
<li><span>The Hope of Broadcasters  </span></li>
<li><span>ICANN Approves Custom Domain Extensions  </span></li>
<li><span>Sciences Ending U.S. Sales  </span></li>
<li><span>LightSquared Proposes Plan to  </span></li>
<li><span>Wimbledon Gets 3D upgrade </span></li>
<li><span>The Hope of Broadcasters  </span></li>
<li><span>LightSquared Proposes Plan to  </span></li>
<li class="last"><span> Newegg Offers $25 7-inch DTV  </span></li>
```

i have stored the above html in a string variable.
what could i do to achieve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are doing this in code behind, which is what I perceive to be the case, try someting like:

```
    var last = htmlString.LastIndexOf("<li>");
    htmlString = htmlString.Remove(last, 4).Insert(last, "<li class=\"last\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string data = ...;
string toReplace ="<li>";
string toPlace = "<li class=\"last\">";
int idx = data.LastIndexOf(toReplace);
data = data.Remove(idx, toReplace.Length).Insert(idx, toPlace);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use jquery to achive this:

```
$("li:last").addClass("last")
```

Comment: actually i am fetching the records in html format from database, so while displaying on the page, i need to add that class, so i need to use .net

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery like this:

```
$("#listid li:last").addClass("last");
```